# Is there a maximum number of items a dictionary can contain?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-internals

We can find the number of items (key-value pairs) that already exist in the dictionary using `len()`.

Apart from the total size of a dictionary being limited by the amount of available memory, is there a limit on the *number* of items a dictionary can contain?

Does it depend on the Python implementation? Does it depend on whether it is a 32-bit or a 64-bit system?

Comment: What makes you think the limitation will come from the CPU or Python itself, rather than, let's say, available memory?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-much-data-can-I-store-in-a-Python-dictionary

Comment: Create an infinite loop that adds keys to the dict. When it crashes, you hit the limit

Comment: Python is fully open source. You can inspect the original code and find out in there -- a deliberately hardcoded limit should be easy to spot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Dictionary Size Maximum Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28891101/python-dictionary-size-maximum-limit)

Comment: @DeepSpace: but that could be a hardcoded limit, or just due to the local enviroment (free amount of RAM, free disk space).

Comment: @usr2564301 I never said the otherwise